# Сортировать таблицу по значению

Tags: c#, sql

Есть БД, добавленная через студию (Microsoft SQL Server 13.00.4001), в ней есть юзеры с полем `score`. Могу ли я в параметрах создания таблицы задать сортировку строк по значению `score` с записью места в поле этой строки, что бы при получении конкретного юзера, знать его место в рейтинге?

Или это можно организовать только через сортировку в коде, получая все строки таблицы?

Comment: В таблицах нет сортировок, там есть только индексы, а для сортировок есть SQL `ORDER BY` https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @aepot мне нужно получать юзера и знать его место в рейтинге (первое, пятое, десятое). Пока не особо понимаю, чем может помочь `ORDER BY`, ибо в этом случае все равно нужно получать всех юзеров, и смотреть, на какой позиции нужный мне юзер

Comment: @Виталий вы можете написать такой SQL звпрос, чтобы сама СУБД посчитала рейтинг юзера и вернула только нужные вам данные в вашу программу. Для этого вам ORDER BY и пригодится.

Comment: Учите SQL, что я еще здесь могу сказать. Без знания языка запросов будет очень сложно работать с базами данных. Представьте, у меня есть база данных, в ней 2 миллиона пользователей (на самом деле больше). И есть всякие рейтинги и статистики, как вы думаете, я реально всех выгружаю, чтобы эти рейтинги посчитать? Окей, допустим я выгрузил и посчитал, работает. А теперь меня просят сделать то же самое, только чтобы работало примерно в 10000 раз быстрее. И тут я узнаю, что есть SQL.

Comment: Думаю, здесь может помочь group by score, потом отсортировать по score и вывести через ROW_NUMBER()?

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения реляционной алгебры все строки в таблице равнозначны, они не имеют порядка. Даже в справке по MS SQL написано, что запрос вида `SELECT * FROM table_name` без `ORDER BY` выполненный несколько раз подряд может вернуть строки в разном порядке.

Чтобы знать место пользователя в рейтинге есть два принципиальных варианта:

1. Выбрать всех юзеров у кого рейтинг не ниже чем у запрошенного, отсортировать, применить ранжирующую функцию, например `ROW_NUMBER` или `DENSE_RANK` (в зависимости от того, будет ли одно общее место при равном `score`), и выбрать из результата одну интересующую строку. Это делается одним SQL-запросом с подзапросом SELECT FROM SELECT.
2. Создать столбец с местом в рейтинге и пересчитывать его на триггерах после

   1. Добавления нового юзера
   2. Удаления юзера
   3. Изменения `score` любого юзера